# for and id attributes in HTML to connect the element

Tags: html, attributes

I saw the code below, in one of my studying codes:

```html
<form>
    <label for="firstName">First Name:(click here cause cursor go inside the input box)</label>
    <input id="firstName" type="text">
</form>
```

I find that the pair of `for` and `id` attributes connect the label and input element in the way that the cursor goes inside the input box automatically by clicking on label.

Which other pair of HTML elements can be connected to each other by the `for` and `id` attributes set? If it works for many other HTML elements, is there any list or source of the default action occurred by connecting one of them in each pair element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/), we can use `for` with `<label>` and `<output>` element. Here is the [link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_for.asp).

Comment: By the way, the question formed in my mind when I see w3school use them just for `label` and `output`. While in my example we see they work same for `input` too. It means maybe there are some other pair of elements which can be connected by `for` and `id` attributes

Comment: The HTML elements mentioned in the link are the only pairs that have this functionality.

Comment: The list in the link is only about the elements can be attributed to `for`. What about `id` attribute? It seems `id` can be attributed only to several types of input elements.

Comment: I believe your question was about the elements with the same relation as the one you mentioned using ```for``` and ```id``` attributes. So the link I shared lists the only 2 HTML elements that the attribute relationship can be used with. As for the ```id``` attribute, it can be used on every HTML element.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a for is important, even if they are adjacent. I seem to recall hearing that some screen readers for the visually impaired have problems otherwise. So if you want to be friendly to those who are perhaps using alternate browsers/screen readers, use this method.

Comment: I'm looking for the list of elements and their default mechanism which can be connected by this pair of attributes.